# How to add rows in function of content of a list in every row in R

Tags: r

I don't know how to duplicate rows by the content of list of every row of a column for example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | 1,2 |
| "b" | 4,5,6 |

My target would be to get this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | 1 |
| "a" | 2 |
| "b" | 4 |
| "b" | 5 |
| "b" | 6 |

Comment: `df |> tidyr::separate_rows(B)`

Comment: I presume the last row of target data should have "b" not "c", right?

Comment: Right sir. I fixed it.

Comment: I like `stack(setNames(strsplit(X$B, ','), X$A))`, where `X` is `df`

Comment: If column B is a list of vectors: `df <- data.frame(A = rep.int(df$A, lengths(df$B)), B = unlist(df$B))`.